# VirtualBox Ubuntu guest does not start under windows 8

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, virtualbox

I have a virtual machine with Ubuntu as guest os. It runs fine until today. Now it is not starting anymore. But I can not figure out why.

It stops here:

```
00:00:36.174538 GUI: UIFrameBufferPrivate::performResize: Size=640x480, Directly using source bitmap content
00:00:36.346276 Display::handleDisplayResize: uScreenId=0 pvVRAM=000000000cf60000 w=640 h=480 bpp=32 cbLine=0xA00 flags=0x1
00:00:36.346322 GUI: UIFrameBufferPrivate::NotifyChange: Screen=0, Origin=0x0, Size=640x480, Sending to async-handler
00:00:36.346390 GUI: UIMachineView::sltHandleNotifyChange: Screen=0, Size=640x480
00:00:36.346404 GUI: UIFrameBufferPrivate::handleNotifyChange: Size=640x480
00:00:36.346416 GUI: UIFrameBufferPrivate::performResize: Size=640x480, Directly using source bitmap content
00:00:39.010190 Display::handleDisplayResize: uScreenId=0 pvVRAM=0000000000000000 w=720 h=400 bpp=0 cbLine=0x0 flags=0x1
00:00:39.010252 GUI: UIFrameBufferPrivate::NotifyChange: Screen=0, Origin=0x0, Size=720x400, Sending to async-handler
00:00:39.010310 GUI: UIMachineView::sltHandleNotifyChange: Screen=0, Size=720x400
00:00:39.010328 GUI: UIFrameBufferPrivate::handleNotifyChange: Size=720x400
00:00:39.010345 GUI: UIFrameBufferPrivate::performResize: Size=720x400, Directly using source bitmap Content
```

I can not add the whole log, because it is to long.

Can anybody help me out?

If needed i can get more informations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i have figured it out what is happend.

Something has changed my os type from 64bit to 32bit. After changing back it works fine.

Comment: How did you change it??